# Change source of data in Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, data-warehouse, netezza

I have been using IBM Netezza as a source of data in Microsoft Power BI, but recently we moved our Data Warehouse on Cloud (Azure). The tables remain the same (only the prefixes are different). I have already made a couple of reports in Power BI when we used IBM netezza, how can I use the same reports, but connect them with Azure??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have already made a couple of reports in Power BI when we used IBM netezza, how can I use the same reports, but connect them with Azure??

Sure. Open the report.  Create a new Power Query query that connects to your new Data Warehouse.  In the Power Query advanced editor compare the query to your Netezza queries, and update your existing queries to connect to the new Data Warehouse.

It should just be a change to the first line or two of the Power Query.